# Is it possible to not repeat a timedtask until the old one has finished?

Tags: java

I have a timed task which could take some time to perform its task, sometimes more than the interval I set.

```
timer.schedule(new ConnectionCheckerThread(), 0,interval);
```

I see that if a thread is still in its run() method another thread is executed after interval.
I don't want that. I'd like that another thread starts JUST when the previous one finished.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TimerTask will not start another thread if the previous task still running, it should queue it to be  executed later.

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) :

> Corresponding to each Timer object is a single background thread that is used to execute all of the timer's tasks, sequentially. Timer tasks should complete quickly. If a timer task takes excessive time to complete, it "hogs" the timer's task execution thread. This can, in turn, delay the execution of subsequent tasks, which may "bunch up" and execute in rapid succession when (and if) the offending task finally completes.

In any case you are better off using [newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor%28%29) instead.

Note : you don't need to schedule your tasks for *periodic* execution, you could simply [schedule](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long%29) next task for single execution in future after completion of current task.

Comment: Yes it right: the effect I get is a rapid succession of threads when the active task takes too long. Do the newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor exibit my requested behaviour?That is: "do not queue any thread, just skip this turn and go to the next interval"

Comment: so, you'd like to have some of your tasks ignored, if the previous one is still ongoing ?

Comment: Exactly! My task, as name suggests, just checks if a connection is up by opening a socket with a certain timeout. This has to be done every x seconds after the previous attempt had place.

Comment: Simply schedule next task (using `Timer` or `Executor`) as the last action of `Runnable\Callable` that does your Connection check. I mean at the end of each task schedule single execution of same task in future. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

Check periodically if the thread is still alive with `Thread.isAlive()` before instanciating a new one.